# MP3 tags in Hebrew show up in gibberish on my phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, languages, hebrew

I have some songs on my computer with Hebrew files names and Hebrew tags.

When I copy them to my phone, the file names appear OK, but the tags appear in gibberish.  This is true both for the default player (I have a Samsung Galaxy S, so that's the default) and for Winamp.

Is there any way to change the font for the tags so that it appears correctly?

Comment: I face same problem with Arabic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem was the encoding that Windows Media Player used.  It uses the Windows Hebrew code-page (1255).  I used [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) with the [Chacon plugin](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_chacon) to change it to the Mac Hebrew code-page (10005) which seems to be supported by my phone.

Comment: So are you aware of a program (or a .NET way) to run a routine that will rename all the file-names and tags to compatible Hebrew, so it doesn't show up in my native MP3 player as gibberish?

Comment: No, I only know how to do it manually using the method above.  Note that this affects Google Music as well, so maybe somebody has addressed this in a forum relevant for that as well.

Comment: This might be useful here. https://superuser.com/questions/1063195/how-to-convert-hebrew-id3-metadata-tags-from-cp1255-to-utf-8